# D3 js unexpected behavior on rapid mouse clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I have a multiline chart using D3, and the lines have nodes to mark the points.  I also have legends below x-axis to display or hide each line when a user clicks on them. Similar to this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/bobmonteverde/2070069)

The chart and legend selection works totally fine when I click normally on legends. But when I click rapidly on legends, one of the lines' nodes disappear. When I inspected the page, I found they got relocated to the top of the browser window(and not visible because there's no svg element there)

I don't even know what the problem is and where should I start debugging as it works fine with normal speed mouse clicks on legends.

I know it is very difficult for anyone to help without looking at the source code or a working fiddle, but I just wanted to know (before I try to reproduce the problem on fiddle) has anyone experienced something like this before? does mouse clicking speed affect how elements get rendered in D3? or this is not a D3 problem at all and some javascript/dom thing I am overlooking?

Comment: No, clicking speed should not affect the way elements are rendered in D3.

Comment: Some "strange" behaviour can occur depending on how your transitions are set up. For example, if there are many transitions attached to the same element, one might be interrupted when another one starts, and that may result on some element not being redrawn on screen (for more about this see https://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/#per-element  "For a given element, transitions are exclusive: only one transition can be running on the element at the same time. Starting a new transition on the element stops any transition that is already running. ")

Comment: I believe this might be the reason. I set the line's `isVisible` property to `true/false` on legend click and redraw the chart again. Will that be considered as a transition?

Comment: @helderdarocha you were right. I moved my legends outside of the parent  `svg>g` element where I was handling all mouse events and transitions for `zoom, tooltip`, etc. and created a separate group `g` for them. This fixed that "unexpected behavior"

Comment: If you can add your comment as an answer  I will accept it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some "strange" behaviour can occur depending on how your transitions are set up. For example, if there are many transitions attached to the same element, one might be interrupted when another one starts, and that may result on some element not being redrawn on screen.

For more about this see [D3 documentation: Working with transitions](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/), specifically [this section](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/#per-element) which explains that "for a given element, transitions are exclusive: only one transition can be running on the element at the same time. Starting a new transition on the element stops any transition that is already running."